# Does std::for_each pass by value or by reference?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, stdmap

I have a test map with pair of std::string and Person pointer

```
class MyMap {
public:
    void clear() {
       std::for_each(people.begin(), people.end(),std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&MyMap::remove), this));
    }
    void remove(std::pair<std::string, Person*> p) { delete p.second; }
private:
    std::map<name, Person*> people;
};
```

My question is does for_each pass each Person pair by ref or value? is it worth using my own, this is a bit cleaner.

In addition to that if I want to use boost::bind or std::bind (c++11) instead of bind1st, how would I do it? should this function be like struct having operator() that inherits std::unary_function?

Comment: "for_each pass each Person pair by ref or value": pass where?if you are talking about the function(3rd argument) it depends on how the function definition is.

Comment: looking at current func. for_each wouldn't accept signature `void remove(std::pair<std::string, Person*>& p)` complains about overloading

Comment: Why does it matter? all your remove function does is delete the Person.

Comment: If you have access to C++11, rather than bothering with `std::bind` just use the range-based version of `for`.

Comment: @Wug Yup I dont want to be passing by value - performance matter!

Comment: PS. std::map has a clear method.

Comment: @LokiAstari calling simply clear method will cause memory leak, its heap allocated Person!

Comment: Silly enter key not doing what I want...

Comment: @dev-inside. Yep. But you should probably not be storing a pointer. std::unique_ptr?

Comment: @LokiAstari c++03 with no boost :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the map is `std::map<name, Person*>`, but the parameter for the `remove` function is `std::pair<std::string, Person*>`. This won't work unless `name` is typedef for `std::string`.

The way your `remove` function is currently defined, you'll make copies of the `map`'s `value_type`. Change the function signature to:

```
void remove(std::pair<const std::string, Person *>& p)
//                    ^^^^^                       ^
//                    key must be const           take a reference
```

To use `std::bind` instead of `std::bind1st`

```
std::for_each( people.begin(), 
               people.end(), 
               std::bind( &MyMap::remove, this, std::placeholders::_1 ) );
```

---

But if you can use C++11 features, there's no need for `std::bind`, lambda is much nicer.

```
std::for_each( people.begin(), 
               people.end(), 
               []( decltype(*people.begin())& p ) { delete p.second; } );
```

or use a range based for loop

```
for( auto&& p : people ) {
    delete p.second;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for_each` will call the functor either by-value or by-reference, depending on how you have defined the functor.

For example:

```
struct Gizmo
{
  bool operator() (const Zippy& rhs) const
  {
    // ...
  }
};
```

This functor is call-by-ref.  However:

```
struct Gizmo
{
  bool operator() (Zippy rhs) const
  {
    // ...
  }
};
```

This one is call-by-value.

Comment: Yup I know that but passing this in std::for_each causes compilation error

:13:   required from ‘void MyMap::clear()’
../src/main.cc:45:34:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/backward/binders.h:125:7: error: ‘typename _Operation::result_type std::binder1st<_Operation>::operator()(typename _Operation::second_argument_type&) const [with _Operation = std::mem_fun1_t<void, MyMap, Person*&>; typename _Operation::result_type = void; typename _Operation::second_argument_type = Person*&]’ cannot be overloaded

Comment: Show us 'Person` and `name`